# What does it mean to be "dependent of a visa holder"?

Tags: visas

So, I'm a high school student (international) trying to apply for a summer school in the United States. During the application process, there's a prompt that asks for my citizenship status, and one option is "Not a US citizen or permanent resident", while another one is "Not a US citizen or permanent resident but dependent of a visa holder". I'm not sure what does that mean. Hope somebody can explain it to me. Thanks!

Update: I asked them and they said they have useable B1 visas, so they should be visa holders I suppose? I don't understand why "dependent of a visa holder" is equivalent to "us citizen or permanent resident" as the answer below suggests (if we just take the words literally!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second option means that you are someone who is in the country as a dependent of someone who is there on a visa.

This could be a child/spouse of someone who is there on a student visa or otherwise visiting.

It does not apply to you.

You should choose "Not a US citizen or permanent resident".

Comment: What if my parents could obtain new B-type visas during that time? But, of course, their old visas are expired now.

Comment: The application is asking about your current status, not what your future status may be.

Comment: Then, does the expired visas make sense? Just want to check that... because the descriptions on that program's site stated that all international students are welcomed to apply, and do not mention any such restrictions in the application form.. :|

Comment: Quite simply, the application is asking **at the time you are filling in the application, are you a US citizen or permanent resident?** The answer is No.

Comment: Don't think about things. Just answer the question directly!

Comment: @fabspro Thanks! It's just that I sometimes complicate things... ;P

Comment: @fabspro Especially in this case when I don't know what "dependent" exactly means.

Comment: Wait... I asked them and they said they have useable B1 visas, so they should be visa holders I suppose?

Comment: I don't understand why in this case "dependent of visa holders" can be translated into "not a us citizen or permanent resident".

Comment: @Macrophage I believe the question you're trying to answer is insufficiently precise.  They mean to say "someone who is living in the US as a dependent of someone else who lives in the US on the basis of a long-term or indefinite visa."  So if your parent or guardian has a B-class visitor visa it doesn't actually change your answer.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. And I'm the one who asks the problem btw :D

Comment: @Macrophage I was referring to the question on the application you're trying to submit.  As to what "dependent" means, it can mean many things, but in general for a minor it denotes the relationship to whoever feeds, clothes, and shelters the minor.

Comment: @phoog Ooh, sorry.... Now I fully understand... Thanks!